# access as little information as possible using facebook connect

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I read a while back that for every extra piece of information requested by a site using facebook connect, the odds of someone signing up using facebook connect to your site decrease dramatically.

At the moment when users sign up they see this from facebook:

> "myAPP will receive the following info: your public profile, friend list, email address and personal description."

How can I decrease it so it just says public profile and email address?

I assume this is where to decrease the amount of info gathered:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me', array('fields' => 'id,email,first_name,last_name'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While login you've added the scopes. Simply remove all the scopes and the user will be asked only for the basic permissions: [**Public Profile and Friends List**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/) - default

But I assume, you need the **email** of the user, so add `email`; and that's it.

I don't know why but you've added `user_about_me` in the permissions list too, you can avoid that if not required, and you'll just see-

> "myAPP will receive the following info: your public profile, friend list, email address"

Comment: Thanks.  Wish I could get rid of the "friends list" as well but unfortunately it seems to be standard.